# execute code at library level after class definition in dart

Tags: dart

So I am trying to migrate a small utility code from JS to Dart and I struggling to find how to do the following:

a registry is used to map Class to a function that is returning a new instance of DifferentClass.

```dart
typedef DifferentClass InstanceGenerator();
Map<Type, InstanceGenerator> _registry;
_registry[ClassDefinition] = () => new DifferentClass();

// at runtime
var a = new ClassDefinition();
var b = _registry[a.runtimeType](); // should resolve to instance of DifferentClass.
```

This all is working fine and well, but the problem I am currently facing is that I need to be able to add to the registry outside of any class's scope and basically at the level of the library. In JS this is implemented as top level call, but in Dart this seem to be not allowed (the DartEditor says NO).

How do I do this pattern in Dart: basically I need to register for each class a function that resolves to an instance of another class and at runtime based on the runtimeType of the instance of the first class create the one registered for it.

Currently it looks like this:

```dart
library whatever;
class ABC {}
Registry.instance.register(ABC, () => new DEF()); // This does not work.
```

Comment: You want the function to be executed when the library is loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put code to be executed at library top-level. 
You can only create functions, classes, enums and typedefs at library top-level.
In Dart everything needs to be called explicitly from `main()` or from anything that was invoked from `main()`

You can create a function like

```dart
library whatever;
class ABC {}
register() => Registry.instance.register(ABC, () => new DEF());
```

then for example from main

```dart
import 'whatever.dart' as we;

main() {
  we.register();
}
```

Alternatively you could use the [initialize](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/initialize) package to do this declarativly.

Comment: The package seem to be matching what I want. One question for it: does it work well enough with the tree shaking, since putting reference to all my classes seem like it might prevent good tree shaking. Basically I want to register all classes with the corresponding render classes, but when compiled it should keep the references only for those classes actually used. In JS this work by simply not including the files of the classes we don't use, but would not probably work in dart...

Comment: I don't know. I suggest to ask the question in an issue in the packages GitHub repo.